# Using hanadb specific function HIERARCHY with R's dbplyr

Tags: sql, r, hana, dbplyr

I am wondering whether one can access the hanadb (SAP) specific [HIERARCHY](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/fc59f81a5c494f399cc2ff70b9c3b4c9.html) function using R's dbplyr library.
I am pretty positive, that this function is not actively supported by dbplyr. But dbplyr's [documentation](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql.html)
states that one should use the `sql()` function in order to combine dplyr statements with literal SQL.

The problem is that the `HIERARCHY` function is not to be used after a `SELECT` clause, but after a `FROM` clause. In this case I cannot figure out how to use the `sql()` function together with the "HIERARCHY"-function in a dbplyr query.

How can I use `sql()` or any other means in order to fit it into a dbplyr query?

Answer (score 0):

This function can be accessed using SQLSCRIPT statements, including SELECT. The syntax for such query:

```sql
select
     * 
from HIERARCHY ( source (
        select "FIELD1" as "NODE_ID",
               "FIELD2" as "PARENT_ID",
                from "TABLE1"
        ) START     WHERE PARENT_ID = '1234567890' ) )
```

Haven't checked with `dplyr::sql()`, but with RODBC worked, have to be the same.